# CSS: make Row background span accross all columns?

Tags: css, background-image

I have a row `<tr>` that has a few columns `<td>` in it. I have a background image set to the `<tr>` but it restarts the background image for each `<td>` as if it were individually set for each `<td>`. I would like the one image to span across the background for all the columns in that row.

Is there a way to do that?

here is my code:

```
<tr bgcolor="#993333" style="color:#ffffff; background:url(images/customer_orders/bar.gif) no-repeat;">
    <td><strong>Product(s)</strong></td>
    <td width="7%"><div align="center"><strong>Qty</strong></div></td>
    <td width="11%"><div align="center"><strong>Total</strong></div></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Side note, unrelated: Instead of putting a "heading" into a cell and marking it up with `<strong>` you should use the `<th>` element.

Comment: A side note for anyone who is trying to do this to make a seamlessly repeating background texture, use "background-attachment: fixed;".  It does not work so well for no-repeat background images, but it will give you a much better solution than either of these answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't change anything if you replace background-repeat property with 'repeat'.
The fact is TR does not support backgrounds and you must do it different way.

If you can use divs - go for it. If you must use table, move your header to seperate table and apply background to this new header-table. This is not perfectly correct but will do the job. If I was you I would use bar.gif graphic that I can repeat-x across all header tds.

```
<table style="background:#993333 url('images/customer_orders/bar.gif'); color:#fff;">
    <tr>
        <th>Product(s)</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>tdata2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to set the background position separately on each `<td>`. `<tr>`s don't support most css properties.

For example, in the simple case where left and right columns are equal widths:

```
tr td{ background-position: center; }
tr td:first-child { background-position: left; }
tr td:last-child { background-position: right; }
```

This obviously gets much more complex when you the widths are different, and in your case with % widths, you would probably have to do some javascript to get the actual location of the middle column.